LiDAR and Camera Fusion
Can anyone tell me about how can I fuse LiDAR and Camera data in a way that the PointClouds are colorised based upon the Image color.For example (in Gazebo Simulation) in an autonomous vehicle there is a camera and a LiDAR both for lane detection. Now the lidar detects the road as a whole detects and shows the pointcloud in rviz, I want to fuse the color of road and lane markings with the pointcloud from the image. I thank you in advance for your answers and suggestions.
I dont have a code rather a pseudo idea because I dont know which library to use and how to use.

Pointcloud2 data has x, y and z values. I would make a matrix of the x y coordinates.
Image data has a matrix as well of color at respective pixel.
Fusing the two together but how no idea


I just managed to do it.
I wrote a code specific to my configuration which projects the 3D points (x, y, z) onto the 2D plane, thus getting the pixel (u, v) whichever laid inside the image's width x height. I extracted the RGB for that pixel (u, v) und added into my custom point field with attributes x, y, z and rgba.
I have uploaded everything to the following repo: https://github.com/ra13o/camera_lidar_fusion.git
